# flickr.com & imagekind.com crashing my browser and effects?

Tags: 11.04, firefox, kubuntu, google-chrome

My Ubuntu 11.04 (installed 2 days ago) is misbehaving.

When I try to upload an image via Flickr or Imagekind my browsers (Firefox and Chrome) crash. It even causes the "Run a Command" window not to respond. When I run `killall -9 <browser-app-name>` the browser window and space on the menu bar remains occupied / in an unusable state.

This problem started happening a couple of days ago. It also has a tendency to crash my window frames and effects, which i use `compiz --restore` to fix.

What could be causing this and how can it be fixed?

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).